# passing a object to a rcp view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to do something like this pseudo-code
   `MyView v = new MyView(); //yeah, I know i can't do this

     v.setObject(myObject);

     v.show();`

my case is: i'm using `swtjasperviewer` to show my reports, and i have to instantiate the report in this jasperviewer, which leave the view opened if the report has no pages...
I want to use a command to open a view, and pass the report to a view, this way, I can use a generic view.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do this:

1. If the object is somehow related to the selection of another view or an editor, then you could use write a SelectionListener that gets the current selection, and then sets the correct object using the following method: `getViewSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(mySelectionListener)`
2. Otherwise, define an object that both your code and the view can reach (e.g. using a static attribute, an OSGi service or an Eclipse extension), and you can use that object to pass information. Your data source updates this object, and you can define a change listener/callback that the view can register himself to.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. i used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003962/passing-parameters-to-the-view), and helped me a lot!