# Passing parameters while showing a view in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating eclipse RCP application and I am stuck with passing parameter while showing a view.
As the first approach, I tried setting a static variable in View2 from View1 and opened that view (as below). It works.

```
IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();               
String viewIdToClose = studentListView.ID;
IViewPart viewToClose = activePage.findView(viewIdToClose);
TableItem item = studentTable.getItem(studentTable.getSelectionIndex());
String text = item.getText(ListViewConstants.TABLE_COLUMN_ONE);
activePage.hideView(viewToClose);
try {
    String viewIdToOpen = StudentReview.ID;
    StudentReview.userId = text;
     activePage.showView(viewIdToOpen);                 
} catch (PartInitException e) {...}
```

As this doesn't seem to be a good approach, I tried as per the suggestion mentioned in the below link(accepted answer).
[Passing parameters to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003962/passing-parameters-to-the-view)
. In this approach, we can pass parameters only after showing the view.

But the issue I have is, the view to be opened should have the value from selected row while calling showView() i.e, I want to populate the parameters in View 2 based on View 1's selection.
Is there any way to achieve this? Is it good to use PULL instead of PUSH approach?
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks!!!

UPDATE 1:
Approach mentioned in [Passing parameters to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003962/passing-parameters-to-the-view)
Interface:

```
public interface ICommunicationView extends IViewPart{
   public void accept(Object parameter);
}
```

Calling accept():

```
IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
String viewIdToClose = StudentListView.ID;
IViewPart viewToClose = activePage.findView(viewIdToClose);
TableItem item = studentTable.getItem(studentTable.getSelectionIndex());
String text = item.getText(ListViewConstants.TABLE_COLUMN_ONE);
activePage.hideView(viewToClose);
try {
   String viewIdToOpen = StudentReview.ID;
   ICommunicationView viewToOpen = (ICommunicationView) activePage.showView(viewIdToOpen);
   viewToOpen.accept(text);//Sending userId to Review view
} catch (PartInitException e) { ... }
```

StudentReviewView:

```
private String studentId;
//getters and setters
@Override
public void accept(Object parameter) {
  setStudentId(parameter.toString());
}

public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
   ...
  System.out.println("Student Id" + this.getStudentId());    
}
```

It prints Student Id as null.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't the accepted answer on the link you mentioned solve your problem?  If you send `userId` to `StudentReviewView` after calling `showView` it will be populated right after being opened, won't it?

Comment: Actually I store student data in XML files with the name <studentId>.xml. In createPartControl() of review view, I will unmarshall the corresponding XML file and populate the components. For that I need studentId while calling createPartControl(). In this case I am getting student ID as null, as createPartControl() is called before sending student ID. I have updated my question.                                                            PS : I have changed variable name from userId to studentId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform calls `createPartControl` when the view is opened by `activePage.showView(viewIdToOpen)`.  So don't populate your fields on `createPartControl`.  Do it when `setStudentId` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the good links try this..

http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/02/07/enhanced-rcp-how-views-can-communicate-the-e4-way/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has a lot of useful information. Unfortunately the approach mentioned wont suit my requirement as I am not using E4. Also I am not sure whether we can use event handling mechanism as the value is needed in View2 before showing it.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. Found a way around it by repacking the specific view component that needs to be updated.
Here is a proof of concept that sets a string:

Setter interface:

```
public interface ViewSetter {    
    void setMessage(String message); 
}
```

View that gets initialized:

```
//view that implements ViewSetter  

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {       
    label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE); //label is a field
}

@Override
public void setMessage(final String message) {
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            label.setText(message);
            label.pack(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Code that creates and initializes the view:

```
IViewPart view = page.showView(viewID);
ViewSetter viewSetter = (ViewSetter)view;
viewSetter.setMessage("Hello World");
```