# Eclipse Plugin RCP: How to pass data between Views

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse Plugin with two views.  I would like to pass an ArrayList from one view to the other view.  I am OK with a Pull model although an Observor based method would be nice too.

The answer here is the closest I've found after much searching:
[Passing parameters while showing a view in Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206509/passing-parameters-while-showing-a-view-in-eclipse-rcp)

However, I don't believe it fits my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in a class that all the views can access.

You could use a singleton class instance managed by the plug-in Activator for example.

If you need to react to changes in class data use listeners to listen for changes to the data. The `org.eclipse.core.runtime.ListenerList` class provides some code to help with listener lists.

For e4 applications you can use a class annotated with `@Creatable` and 
`@Singleton` and inject it where required. For e4 you can use the Event Broker to broadcast events.