# Eclipse RCP: how to register an ISourceProviderListener

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, view, eclipse-rcp, listener

today i tried the following:

I have:

- a View with a form (**FormView**)
- a `AbstractSourceProvider` (**Provider**) to provide changes in **FormView** to the world
- a View (**ConsumerView**) that should consume information from **Provider** it implements `ISourceProviderListener`

**FormView** updates the **Provider**, which fires the `fireSourceChanged`. But how can I register the **ConsumerView** so that it listens for changes in the **Provider**?

This answer here on stackoverflow, did not really explain how to do it: 
[How to communicate between views in Eclipse RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227701/how-to-communicate-between-views-in-eclipse-rcp)

Also Lars Vogels tutorials on RCP Commands are mentioned frequently, but I don't get it from there.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within your **ConsumerView** `createPartControl(..)` method:

```
ISourceProviderService service = (ISourceProviderService)getSite().getService(ISourceProviderService.class);

ISourceProvider yourProvider = service.getSourceProvider("yourSourceProviderName");

yourProvider.addSourceProviderListener(this);
```