# Registering an ISourceProvider in Services (Eclipse Plugin Development, RCP)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am in a situation similar to the one described in these stackoverflow questions:
[How to communicate between views in Eclipse RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227701/how-to-communicate-between-views-in-eclipse-rcp) and
[Eclipse RCP: how to register an ISourceProviderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874874/eclipse-rcp-how-to-register-an-isourceproviderlistener)

I tried following DJ.'s instructions from the first link, but am stuck at the point where I'm supposed to 'Create an implementation of ISourceProvider and register it in the services'. The ISourceProvider implementation exists, but I am not sure where and how to register a service.

This is what I've got so far:
In my MANIFEST.MF under Extensions I added org.eclipse.ui.services.
According to [the Eclipse documentation for Services](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_services.html) I need another class implementing a Service (ISourceProviderService, I assume) and some kind of ServiceFactory. Unfortunately, I haven't found a lot of helpful documentation for these two classes.

Or am I missing something and there exists a way to communicate between views that is way simpler?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the involved classes, but did you have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html)? It seems to contain a few examples with good explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've found myself on that page a couple of times, but thought it wasn't relevant because it was focusing on commands (I am trying to make an instance of an object accessible to two views). In the meantime I found [this tutorial](http://www.techjava.de/topics/2009/07/passing-data-between-plug-ins/) to be very helpful. It's still not quite working, but at least now I think I'm starting to understand what's going on.

(Why does your user name seem familiar?)