# Double click event prob

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When ever I double click the tree viewer file that file name should appear in the next form view

Sample.dat -> double click -> name should be appear Sample.dat and File related properties should be appear.
I created a treeViewer files and double click the file name that name is not appear.
Please kindly help me reg this,eclipse rcp,Juno,e4 etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click listener to your tree

```
final Tree tree = new Tree(parent, SWT.BORDER);
tree.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        //get data of selected element
        //we use array[0], because we have not multiselect tree
        MyDataObject data = (MyDataObject) tree.getSelection()[0].getData();

        //now you need to pass "data" to your view with file info
        //I don't know how to do it in pre e4 RCP apps, so
        //please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227764/1030113
        //hope that helps

    }
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {}
});

//to test
TreeItem treeItem1 = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
treeItem1.setText("some item 1");
treeItem1.setData(new MyDataObject("somedata 1"));

TreeItem treeItem2 = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
treeItem2.setText("some item 2");
treeItem2.setData(new MyDataObject("somedata 2"));
```

I don't know how to communicate between view in pre e4 RCP apps, but I found some usefull answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227764/1030113

Comment: Please Implementing in Eclipse RCP,swt,jface,Juno etc.. technologies.As per my knowledge above your code is in awt,swing etc.. Thank you.

Comment: Actualy, it's SWT code. It uses following classes: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree, org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem, org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener, org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent.

Comment: I am working here eclipse rcp,swt,juno,java based application.

Comment: When ever I double click the tree viewer file that file name should appear in the next form view as a heading file name
Sample.dat -> double click -> name should be appear Sample.dat and File related properties should be appear.
I created a treeViewer files and double click the file name that name is not appear.
Please kindly help me reg this,eclipse rcp,Juno,e4 etc.. 
Please I set the 3 views properly in the Perspective class

Comment: Did some edit of my answer, hope it would be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Perspective class...
private void setLayouts(IPageLayout layout) {
        // Range 0.05f to 0.95f....
        IFolderLayout explorerFolderLayout = layout.createFolder("explorer", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, layout.getEditorArea());

### explorerFolderLayout.addView(ExplorerView.ID);

view class..
viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();

            FileName fn = null;
            FileNameContainer fnc = null;
            if (selection.isEmpty()) 
                return;

            List<Object> list = selection.toList();...
```

....